# Private methods suddenly inaccessible when chaining

Tags: c++

I have a simple class hierarchy with a base class and a derived class. The base has two protected members that the derived class calls. Coming from some recent C# experiences, I thought it would be good to make the interface a bit more fluent and allow chaining of method calls, so instead of calling `this->A()`, then `this->B()` you can call `this->A()->B()`. However, the following code will not compile:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
  protected:
    Base* A()
    {
      std::cout << "A called." << std::endl;    
      return this;
    }

    Base* B()
    {
      std::cout << "B called." << std::endl;    
      return this;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    void Test()
    {
        // Base::A and Base::B are private here.
        this->A()   // This works fine
            ->B();  // Suddenly I cannot access my own private method?
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.Test();

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following compiler error:

```
main.cpp: In member function 'void Derived::Test()':
main.cpp:12:15: error: 'Base* Base::B()' is protected
         Base* B()
               ^
main.cpp:26:21: error: within this context
                 ->B();  // Suddenly I cannot access my own private method?
                     ^
```

I also tried making the base class methods virtual, but that didn't help.

My C++ is rusty enough that I can't seem to figure out what is going on here, so help would be much appreciated. Also I was wondering if this is a bad idea because `C++ != C#` and C++-people aren't used to such fluent interfaces.

Comment: Erm `B` is protected, not private.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A protected member in a class is accessible from a derived class only through that derived class, i.e. through an object of, or reference or pointer to, that derived class.

The return type of `A()` is `Base*`, which is not the derived class, which is why you can't access its protected members. The compiler doesn't track that it really refers to the same object.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work when the functions are virtual? In that case the compiler won't have to keep track of the pointer,right?. So it should have got resolved correctly at runtime, shouldn't  it?

Comment: The functions being virtual or not has nothing to do with the return type. In fact, them being virtual would make it *worse*, since the compiler could no longer inline the functions and realize that they're just returning `this`. Not that inlining ever plays a part in C++'s validity analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you cannot call protected methods of `Base` class from `Base *`. You can think as protected methods are private with a difference that they become private of a derived class as well.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that is too bad. Guess I'll just forget about the idea then, as providing this slight readability improvement is not worth making everything `public` for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behavior, you cannot call a protected function for a different class you can only do through the derived class, because when you call `this->A()` it returns a Base* which is a different class. The reason is, what if you did something like,

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    void Test()
    {
       baseInstance->B(); // this shouldn't be possible. If the case was you can call it through a pointer or an object this would be possible.
    }

    Base* baseInstance; 
};
```

Also it's good to point out that the derived and base `this` might not have the same address, it could have a different address. When you actually cast the `Base*` to `Derived*` the compiler will handle the difference in address, which makes it possible that's why it works if it was done like this `static_cast<Derived*>(this->A())->B();`

Comment: I see that concept3d, my question arose from the expectation that when I return a pointer to `this` in a base call, then it would return the `this`-pointer to the caller, i.e. the derived object; in particular if the method is `virtual`.

Comment: @CompuChip The derived and base `this` might not have the same address, it could have a different address I wrote an article about it http://codingshuttle.com/2013/10/the-c-effect-part-1/.

Comment: @CompuChip If you actually cast the `Base*` to `Derived*` the compiler will handle the difference in address and will be essentially the same instance, which makes it possible that's why it works if it was done like this `static_cast<Derived*>(this->A())->B();`

Comment: Thanks. Interesting reading @ that link. I probably also have some NULL-guards around my `delete`s :-)

Answer (score 2):

To add to Sebastian, this can be resolved, but not nicely, by:

```
static_cast<Derived*>(this->A())->B();
```

Comment: Thanks PunyOne, in that case I prefer `this->A(); this->B();` or actually just `A(); B();`. The whole point of the exercise was to increase readability, not decrease it :)

Answer (score 2):

Your can refer the standard to get the answer to your problem

11.2 Accessibility of base classes and base class members [class.access.base]

> A base class B of N is accessible at R, if

```
— an invented public member of B would be a public member of N, or
— R occurs in a member or friend of class N, and an invented public member of B would be     
    a private or
    protected member of N, or
— R occurs in a member or friend of a class P derived from N, and an invented public member of B would be a private or protected member of P, or
— there exists a class S such that B is a base class of S accessible at R and S is a base class of N accessible at R
```

If you are referring the member via Base pointer, none of the above clause statisfies.

Comment: +1 for referencing the standard. According to the second point, if I make `Derived` a friend of `Base` it will work... but writing `friend Derived` in the base class feels wrong on so many levels that I won't even admit I've tried to see if it compiles.